# Return mutable version of struct in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a methods that results the struct itself using `return self`

Unfortunately I am getting the Immutable value of type "Struct name" only has mutable member name 'method name' error.

How can I return such that the struct is mutable?

Comment: show your code and full error message (also indicate which line)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can mutate structs just fine, but you have to annotate those mutating methods with `mutating`.

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var x:Int = 0
    mutating func increment() {
        x++;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Let me make some clarifications here. Structs can be mutated:

```
var structA = SomeStruct()
structA.x // 0
structA.increment()
structA.x // 1
```

But only if you declared it as `var`. This will not compile:

```
let structA = SomeStruct()
// structA.increment() // Compile error
```

Now when you do something like `something.methodReturningStruct().mutatingMethod()`, the `methodReturningStruct()` will actually return a copy of the original struct (by virtue of value types). But since you didn't assign it to a `var`, it will implicitly be treated as a constant (i.e. `let`) so you get that compiler error.

You can still do the same thing, but you just have to tell swift to use the struct as a `var`

```
var structB = something.methodReturningStruct()
structB.mutatingMethod()
```

Comment: You can't mutate them directly from the return of another method. `structA.methodReturningSelf().mutatingMethod()`

Comment: That's because you chained it. The compiler sees that `methodReturningSelf()` returns a copy of the original `structA`, but you called a method directly on it without assigning it (making the new copy useless, as well as the call to the `mutatingMethod()` useless. This will work fine: `var structB = structA.methodReturningSelf(); structB.mutatingMethod()`. Note the `var` usage instead of `let`.